# extracting attributes from an html page using rvest package

Tags: html, r, attributes, rvest

i'm trying to extract data from this site
http://www.mycity4kids.com/Delhi-NCR/Schools_bl

```
<div class="normal_listing" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div class="row rowpdng">
<div class="col-lg-2 hidden-xs" style="padding:0;">
<a href="/Delhi-NCR/Schools/Amazon-Public-School_Sector-56-Gurgaon/5038_bd"><img itemprop="logo" src="http://images.mycity4kids.com/business-image/10369/amazon-international-school130312082644.JPG" alt="Amazon Public School" title="Amazon Public School" width="108" height="60" class="img-border"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="innerdiv">
<h1>
<a itemprop="url" class="biznme_txt" title="Amazon Public School" id="Nmeof5038" href="/Delhi-NCR/Schools/Amazon-Public-School_Sector-56-Gurgaon/5038_bd"> <span style="color:#3273da;right:0px;top:0px;" itemprop="name">Amazon Public School</span>
</a>
</h1>
<h2> <span itemprop="location" style="right:0px;top:0px;"> <a href="/Delhi-NCR/Schools_Sector-56-Gurgaon_Gurgaon_bl"  class="loclink" title="Schools in Sector 56 Gurgaon">Schools in Sector 56 Gurgaon </a> 
</span>
</h2>
```

the info i require here is in the 4th line of code snippet above i.e. "/Delhi-NCR/Schools/Amazon-Public-School_Sector-56-Gurgaon/5038_bd" i can't figure out a way to do so.
Suggest a way to do so asap!

Comment: What are you trying to do with this info? There are many solutions but you might need permission from the website to use their data...

Comment: i simply need this data for analysis of the region on basis of educational institutes present in the region. just a project of mine, which i need to present in about 10-11 hours from now.  p.s. i simply need that text there, not the link